# OpenFire appears to Ignore RosterPacket.ItemType.both Packets

Tags: xmpp, openfire, asmack

I have a Strange Problem With Roster Packets, I am not New to aSmack, but i never had this problem before, appearantly my OpenFire Server is Ignoring this kind of packet :

```
       RosterPacket ropack = new RosterPacket();
       ropack.setType(IQ.Type.SET);
       RosterPacket.Item item  = new RosterPacket.Item("admin@reza-hp", null);
       item.setItemType(RosterPacket.ItemType.both);
       ropack.addRosterItem(item);
       try {
        MyService.connection.sendPacket(ropack);
    } catch (NotConnectedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and it ignores the type and it returns this :

```
 iq type="set" id="693-6" to="reza@reza-
 hp/Smack" query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster" item jid="admin@reza-hp" 
 subscription="from"/ /query> /iq
```

recently i read that server must ignores any roster item type but the "remove", is that right? if it is so how am i supposed to accept the friend requests on the server side?

Answer (score 0):

Roster is used for presence subscription. That's its main purpose. Therefore, you are not supposed to *edit* the roster. You should use the subscription workflow and ask to subscribe to the other contact presence (or unsubscribe).

XMPP servers will care for you about keeping the roster item in the correct state according to presence subscription workflow.

For reference please read XMPP specifications: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6121#section-3.1

Comment: ye thats what i finally did how its actually a limit,its just amazing how it was working few days ago and now its not ! any way ty